# Get year from cell and create a different date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of various dates. I process each of these dates as part of a loop.  I need to get a date, March 31st and the year from the cell.
For example:

```
4/5/2014     3/31/2014  
7/5/1999     3/31/1999
```

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DateSerial:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = DateSerial(Year(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")), 3, 31)
```

Comment: Thanks. DateSerial is what I needed